# Redirect example.com to www.example.com VPS & Apache2

Tags: apache2, dns, debian, vps

I have a VPS and a domain name registered with the provider.

When I enter www.example.com my site is displayed correctly, but entering example.com does not work. I am able to ping www.example.com.

I added the following line to my apache2 default vhosts file:

```
ServerName example.com
ServerAlias www.example.com
```

But this did not work.

The VPS is a Debian5 OS.

Any ideas?
Note: There is no option via a provided control panel to add this, it's a basic package I purchased

Thanks

### ANSWER

https://serverfault.com/questions/283663/redirect-example-com-to-www-example-com-vps-apache2

Comment: Apache configuration is off-topic here (it's not programming-related, it's server software configuration). Voting to migrate to [serverfault](http://serverfault.com), which is more appropriate.

Comment: Did you try it the other way around?

Comment: Ok...I'll add it there Ken. I wasn't aware of serverfault.

Answer (score 0):

Check your DNS first (dig/nslookup)

dig www.example.com
   dig example.com

Chances are example.com isn't referring to anything, or a different host, CNAME or ip address.

Add a catch all record if you wish: *.example.com

How to manage DNS depends on your ISP/Hosting provider

Comment: I'll add that catch all sehe. I have linked solution to answer. Cheers

Comment: Wut? Oh, wait! That spot right there... is what we folks around here like to call "the question" :)